# Skipped 148 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread, android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I am creating a lot of edittext and texviews programmatically, and putting them in tablelayout. 
This is my code

```
private EditText[] etAgreedVolume, etAgreedSaleParty, etAgreedSalesMgr;

private void createOrderTable(ArrayList<POJOOrder> orderList) {
    etAgreedVolume = new EditText[orderList.size()];
    etAgreedSaleParty = new EditText[orderList.size()];
    etAgreedSalesMgr = new EditText[orderList.size()];
    int maxLength = 3;
    InputFilter[] FilterArray = new InputFilter[1];
    FilterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength);

    for (int i = 0; i < orderList.size(); i++) {
        TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(getActivity());
        tableRow.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        TextView tvItem = new TextView(getActivity());
        tvItem.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        tvItem.setText(orderList.get(i).getBrandWith_SKU());
        tvItem.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#2E3B41"));
        tvItem.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tvItem.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        tvItem.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rectangle_grey);

        TextView tvPlannedVolume = new TextView(getActivity());
        tvPlannedVolume.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        tvPlannedVolume.setText(orderList.get(i).getPlannedVolume() + " CS");
        tvPlannedVolume.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#2E3B41"));
        tvPlannedVolume.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tvPlannedVolume.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        tvPlannedVolume.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rectangle_grey);

        LinearLayout linearLayout1 = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        linearLayout1.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        linearLayout1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        TextView tvPlannedSalesParty = new TextView(getActivity());
        tvPlannedSalesParty.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1f));
        tvPlannedSalesParty.setText(orderList.get(i).getPlannedSalesPromoParty() + "");
        tvPlannedSalesParty.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#2E3B41"));
        tvPlannedSalesParty.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tvPlannedSalesParty.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        tvPlannedSalesParty.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rectangle_grey);

        TextView tvPlannedSalesMgr = new TextView(getActivity());
        tvPlannedSalesMgr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1f));
        tvPlannedSalesMgr.setText(orderList.get(i).getPlannedSalesPromoMgr() + "");
        tvPlannedSalesMgr.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#2E3B41"));
        tvPlannedSalesMgr.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tvPlannedSalesMgr.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        tvPlannedSalesMgr.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rectangle_grey);

        linearLayout1.addView(tvPlannedSalesParty);
        linearLayout1.addView(tvPlannedSalesMgr);

        etAgreedVolume[i] = new EditText(getActivity());
        etAgreedVolume[i].setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        etAgreedVolume[i].setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), android.R.color.black));
        etAgreedVolume[i].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        etAgreedVolume[i].setHintTextColor(Color.parseColor("#888888"));
        etAgreedVolume[i].setHint("0");
        etAgreedVolume[i].setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        etAgreedVolume[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rectangle_grey);
        etAgreedVolume[i].setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        etAgreedVolume[i].addTextChangedListener(watcherAgreedVolume);
        etAgreedVolume[i].setFilters(FilterArray);

        LinearLayout linearLayout2 = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        linearLayout2.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        linearLayout2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        etAgreedSaleParty[i] = new EditText(getActivity());
        etAgreedSaleParty[i].setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1f));
        etAgreedSaleParty[i].setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), android.R.color.black));
        etAgreedSaleParty[i].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        etAgreedSaleParty[i].setHintTextColor(Color.parseColor("#888888"));
        etAgreedSaleParty[i].setHint("0");
        etAgreedSaleParty[i].setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        etAgreedSaleParty[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rectangle_grey);
        etAgreedSaleParty[i].setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        etAgreedSaleParty[i].addTextChangedListener(watcherAgreedVolume);
        etAgreedSaleParty[i].setFilters(FilterArray);

        etAgreedSalesMgr[i] = new EditText(getActivity());
        etAgreedSalesMgr[i].setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1f));
        etAgreedSalesMgr[i].setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), android.R.color.black));
        etAgreedSalesMgr[i].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        etAgreedSalesMgr[i].setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        etAgreedSalesMgr[i].setHintTextColor(Color.parseColor("#888888"));
        etAgreedSalesMgr[i].setHint("0");
        etAgreedSalesMgr[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rectangle_grey);
        etAgreedSalesMgr[i].setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        etAgreedSalesMgr[i].addTextChangedListener(watcherAgreedVolume);
        etAgreedSalesMgr[i].setFilters(FilterArray);

        linearLayout2.addView(etAgreedSaleParty[i]);
        linearLayout2.addView(etAgreedSalesMgr[i]);

        tableRow.addView(tvItem);
        tableRow.addView(tvPlannedVolume);
        tableRow.addView(linearLayout1);
        tableRow.addView(etAgreedVolume[i]);
        tableRow.addView(linearLayout2);

        tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
    }
}
```

This page of my app becomes too slow. Sometimes even ANR occurs due to heavy work.
How can I make it smooth.

Comment: it sounds to me like you should be using a RecyclerView instead of TableView. RecyclerView will only create the views actually being show on the screen, and while scrolling through it recyclers them. Thou avoiding this massive amount of work u see

Comment: consider using RxJava to create all views or use RecyclerView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to use listView to create the views. 
Tablelayout is not able to hold this much huge data.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

Create an [`AsyncTask`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and do all the processing there, finally set the layout elements in `onPostExecute` of the `AsyncTask`. Additionally you may want to show a [`ProgressBar`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html) during the execution of your `AsyncTask`, and dismiss it in `onPostExecute`.

Scroll down to the subtitle "The 4 steps" in the [`AsyncTask` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to get a better understanding of this solution.

**Option 2**

Create an XML file (e.g. myTableRow.xml) that holds your `TableRow` with all of its children, set all of the common parameters, i.e. parameters that do not depend on the `iterator integer i`. So basically you are creating a template of your `TableRow` common to all.

Then in the `for Loop` all you are left to do is: Inflate `myTableRow.xml` for each iteration, set the remaining parameters (dependent on `i`) and finally add it to the `tableLayout`.

Note: It should be possible to already add your `EditText` views `etAgreedVolume[i]`, `etAgreedSaleParty[i]` and `etAgreedSalesMgr[i]` to the XML file (i.e., your `TableRow` template) despite them being dependent on `i`. I suggest you do so by simply creating (standard) `EditText` views, then once you have inflated the `TableRow` you can retrieve these `EditTexts` and add them to the array.

I cannot guarantee that "Option 2" would run things faster or smoother for that matter, however, in most cases inflating a layout is faster than creating a layout using hard-coded java.

Answer (score -2):

Update your views on a seperate Uithread
sample:

```
private void runThread() {

new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        while (/*your condition*/) {
            try {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //update your views here
                    }
                });

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}.start();
}
```

if you update your views which in your case are many, main thread will do a lot of work resulting in skipping frames and ANRs